# Use different images depending on screen orientation

Tags: android

I know you can put different layouts in different folders (port and landscape) 
How can I put different images depending on the layout?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use seperate drawable folders like

```
// for Phones
drawable-ldpi
drawable-mdpi
drawable-hdpi

//for 7 inch tablets
drawable-large-mdpi
drawable-large-hdpi(for Nexus 7)

// for 10 inch tablets
drawable-xlarge-mdpi
```

and for different orientations

```
drawable-land-hdpi
drawable-port-hdpi
```

Refer [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html) to read more about providing resources..

In this case, if you stick with all of those folders, you need to put one image in each, sized to match the indicated screen density.

Please Refer the [docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#overview)

Comment: For the land and port, as you can see it only takes layout. How can I put different image sizes land and port.

Comment: Screen density is different  from screen orientation. I am talking about having the same density but I want the image be  big in case of landscape and small in case of portrait. It is a custom progress bar

Comment: yes..did you try putting big image in `drawable-land-hdpi`and a small one in `drawable-port-hdpi` ?

Comment: Oh awesome... Sorry I missed that.. Thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

Just use same xml for both folder, and put the desire Image to landScape and the desire to portrait.